# What happens to the calls to Azure Storage Account DURING a FAILOVER?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, failover, azure-storage-account

We have an Azure Storage Account in US EAST 2 location which has RA-GRS replication.
In case of a disaster, either client(us) or Azure(Azure Managed Failover) can initiate a FAILOVER and once FAILOVER is completed (lets say it takes 10 minutes to complete) the secondary region's storage account becomes primary and caters the requests(both read and write.

My question is, what happens to the "read" calls during those 10 minutes when FAILOVER is happening ? Will those "read" calls be fulfilled by secondary region storage account since we have RA-GRS or is there any catch ? I have this confusion because, although secondary region's storage account is always available for "read" requests, but the application has to specifically point to that secondary storage account to make a call otherwise the call goes to primary storage by default.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and post your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description in the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/geo-redundant-design#running-your-application-in-read-only-mode), read requests can be redirected to the secondary region.

[image]

Comment: Ok, to sum up your response, can I say that, if handled programmatically(meaning may be using resiliency to check failure), in case of a outage and DURING FAILOVER, the read requests can be fulfilled by secondary region, right ? @Frank Gong

Comment: I did not understand what you said `if handled programmatically(meaning may be using resiliency to check failure)`, but my understanding is that as long as you use a `RA-GRS` type of storage account, in case of a outage and DURING FAILOVER, the read requests can be fulfilled by secondary region.@KarunAhluwalia

Comment: Thanks @Frank Gong